# Assign post to a category automatically based on post title keyword

Tags: php, wordpress

I used the code bellow to assign posts in bulk to a certain category based on a keyword from post's title.

**The code bellow should identify all the posts with keyword 'addiction' in the title and to add them to the categories with id 6 and 8.**

For some reasons it is not working anymore.

```
add_action('publish_post', 'update_categories');
function update_categories(){
    global $wpdb, $post;
    // set the category ID to update
    $categories = array(6,8);
    echo "updating";
    $postids = array();
    // this is to tell the script to only pull posts that are labeled "publish"
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    );
    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($my_query->have_posts()):
        while ($my_query->have_posts()):
            $my_query->the_post();
            $postids[] = $my_query->post->ID;
        endwhile;
    endif;

    wp_reset_query(); // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
    $i = 0;
    $num_of_posts = $my_query->post_count;
    // running through all the posts
    while ($num_of_posts > $i):
        // getting the post title
        $post_title = get_the_title($postids[$i]);
        if (stripos($post_title, 'addiction') !== false):
            // add a category
            wp_set_post_categories($postids[$i], $categories, true);
        endif;
        $i++;
    endwhile;
}
```

Can you guys please help?

Comment: Could you explain what exactly is not working with the given code?

Comment: Hello Nico,thank you for your time. After I am trying to update a post and to trigger the action. I see on Updating text on white screen. Nothing happens and the posts are not added to the categories anymore. We have around 7000 posts in the database.

Comment: @Alex Manole you should change `publish_post` to `save_post` because `publish_post` works only the first time post is published and `save_post` works for updating, creating a post or import too

Comment: @Manjunath It is still not working :( Don't know what else I can do. The debug function it is activate, the debug log it is activated but it is nothing there. Empty. No errors at all.

Comment: @NicoHaase Any thoughts? Thank you

Comment: Have you even tried debugging? Is this function called? How many post IDs does it aggregate? Does it call `wp_set_post_categories` afterwards?

Comment: @AlexManole Check my answer, also check if categories exists. I added a function to check that too

Comment: @Manjunath Thank you for your time. It s working fine now. It was a mix of issues. Memory issues and debug issues because for some reasons I was not able to see the debug messages on the screen. After I was deactivating all the plugins I was able to see the memory issue. On one run, the function it is eating around 600 MB Ram and 80% of the processor.

Comment: @Nico Haase Thank you for your time. It s working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a code with debugging for checking what is and what not are working. Update values according to your needs and check if it works.

```
//To Add Categories to all posts containing specific word in post title
function add_categories_to_posts(){
    echo "<br><br>Updating Categories Started <br><br>";

    $query_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post', //post type - default post type is 'post'
        'post_status' => 'publish', //published posts
        'posts_per_page' => - 1, //-1 is used to get all posts 
    );

    $all_posts = new WP_Query($query_args);

    $new_categories_list = array(6,8,10,22);
    $working_categories = []; //Debug : list of categoires that does not exists from given list
    $not_working_categories = []; //Debug : list of categoires that exists from given list
    $updated_posts_ids = [];    //Debug : list of post id's that updated categories
    $not_updated_posts_ids = []; //Debug : list of post id's that did not updated any categories

    //Debug : check if post categories exists
    foreach ($new_categories_list as $key => $category) {
        $exists = term_exists($category,'category');
        if ( $exists !== 0 && $exists !== null ) {
            $working_categories[] = $category; 
        } 
        else{
            $not_working_categories[] = $category;
        }
    }

    if($all_posts->have_posts()){
        while ( $all_posts->have_posts() ) : $all_posts->the_post();
            $title = get_the_title();
            $ID = get_the_ID();
            if (stripos($title, 'addiction') !== false){
                $updated_posts_ids[] = $ID;
                wp_set_post_categories($ID, $working_categories, true); 
                //set true as last argument since you don't want to override existing categories
            } else{
                $not_updated_posts_ids[] = $ID;
            }
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    echo "<br>Affected Post ID's array: ";
    var_dump($updated_posts_ids);
    echo "<br><br>Unaffected Post ID's array: ";
    var_dump($not_updated_posts_ids);

    echo "<br><br>Updating Categories Ended <br><br>";
}
add_action('save_post','add_categories_to_posts');
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. It s working fine now. It was a mix of issues. Memory issues and debug issues because for some reasons I was not able to see the debug messages on the screen. After I was deactivating all the plugins I was able to see the memory issue. On one run, the function it is eating around 600 MB Ram and 80% of the processor.